# MTLS certificate error

Tags: sandbox, authentication, certificates, tls

I have been breaking my head to get the Mutual Authentication(MTLS) to work in Salesforce for a while but with little success. I am trying this out on a sandbox by enabling this feature and by assigning the required permission set to the API only user.

I have tried with both a Self-signed certificate and with a certificate signed by a CA internal to our company but it gives me different errors for both. As mentioned in [this](https://blog.superpat.com/2018/01/25/salesforce-mutual-authentication-part-1-the-basics/) blog, is it mandatory to generate certificates only from the list of predefined CAs to get it to work even in sandboxes? I assume I would have to spend some money to get one such certificate which sounds unreasonable considering the fact that I am trying this on a sandbox.

The following are the errors I get

```
Certificate error: unable to get local issuer certificate

Certificate error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
```

Comment: Please also make sure that the "full chain" is in your certificate https://www.digicert.com/kb/ssl-support/pem-ssl-creation.htm

Comment: @BryanAnderson, I do not have any intermediate certificates. So, I don't think I need to worry about the chain part. Or do I?

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000318715&type=1&mode=1 "The API client needs to send a client certificate chain - the client certificate along with all intermediate certificates that exist in the trust path between the client certificate and its root certificate - to Salesforce during the TLS handshake"

Comment: I finally managed to get the right certificate to be used and when I try to get userInfo with the certificate, I get nothing in the response. Somewhere in the response, I see this message 'ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol'. I am at least happy it doesn't speak anything about the certs. Any idea how will I be able to find out what's going wrong?